# how to remove inner border and keep outer border from Custom Alert Box

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have created Custom alert box working as expected but need to modify css. Alert b0x contain three Div element and i dint specify any border property for that div element Eventhough i am getting Border for each div element.

I want to remove inside border expect last border

I tried `style="border: none !important;"` but not working

```js
function CustomAlert() {
    this.render = function (dialog) {
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dilogoverlay = document.getElementById('dilogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dilogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dilogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW / 2) - (550 * .5) + "px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dilogboxhead').innerHTML = "My Message";
        document.getElementById('dilogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dilogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick=Alert.ok()">OK</button>';

    }
    this.ok = function () {
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dilogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

```css
#dilogoverlay {
    display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1100;
}

#dialogbox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 1px;
    width: 550px;
    z-index: 1100;
}

#dialogbox > div {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 8px;
}

#dialogbox > div > dilogboxhead {
    background: #666;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #CCC;
}

#dialogbox > div > dilogboxbody {
    background: #333;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#dialogbox > div > dilogboxfoot {
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="dilogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox" style="border: none !important;">
    <div id="dilogboxhead" style="text-align: left;"></div>
    <div id="dilogboxbody" style="text-align: center;"></div>
    <div id="dilogboxfoot" style="text-align: right;"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to remove Highlighted border and adding background color as light blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function CustomAlert() {
      this.render = function(dialog) {
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dilogoverlay = document.getElementById('dilogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dilogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dilogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW / 2) - (550 * .5) + "px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dilogboxhead').innerHTML = "My Message";
        document.getElementById('dilogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dilogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick=Alert.ok()">OK</button>';

      }
      this.ok = function() {
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dilogoverlay').style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    var Alert = new CustomAlert();
    Alert.render();
```

```css
    #dilogoverlay {
      display: none;
      opacity: .8;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1100;
    }

    #dialogbox {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      /* background: #000; // this bg appearing due to margin creating gaps in child divs */
      border-radius: 1px;
      width: 550px;
      z-index: 1100;
border:1px solid black;
    }

    #dialogbox>div {
      background: #FFFFFF;
      margin: 8px;
    }

    #dialogbox>div>dilogboxhead {
      background: #666;
      font-size: 19px;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #CCC;
    }

    #dialogbox>div>dilogboxbody {
      background: #333;
      padding: 20px;
      color: #FFF;
    }

    #dialogbox>div>dilogboxfoot {
      background: #666;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="dilogoverlay"></div>
    <div id="dialogbox">
      <div id="dilogboxhead" style="text-align: left;"></div>
      <div id="dilogboxbody" style="text-align: center;"></div>
      <div id="dilogboxfoot" style="text-align: right;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you please explain mw where abjectly did you change

Comment: 1) Remove "border: none" from style attribute of <div id="dialogbox">
2) Add rule "border:1px solid black;" to #dialogbox

Answer (score 1):

The 'border' is appearing because you've added `8px` of margin to each `div` in the alert. This allows the black background colour of `#dialogbox` to be displayed through the gaps.

To fix this either remove the margin on the `div` or get rid of the background colour on `#dialogbox`.

In this example I did the latter:

```js
function CustomAlert() {
  this.render = function(dialog) {
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerHeight;
    var dilogoverlay = document.getElementById('dilogoverlay');
    var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
    dilogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dilogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";
    dialogbox.style.left = (winW / 2) - (550 * .5) + "px";
    dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
    dialogbox.style.display = "block";
    
    document.getElementById('dilogboxhead').innerHTML = "My Message";
    document.getElementById('dilogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
    document.getElementById('dilogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick=Alert.ok()">OK</button>';

  }
  this.ok = function() {
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dilogoverlay').style.display = "none";
  }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
Alert.render();
```

```css
#dilogoverlay {
  display: none;
  opacity: .8;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1100;
}

#dialogbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  /* background: #000; // this bg appearing due to margin creating gaps in child divs */
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1px;
  width: 550px;
  z-index: 1100;
}

#dialogbox>div {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 8px;
}

#dialogbox>div>dilogboxhead {
  background: #666;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #CCC;
}

#dialogbox>div>dilogboxbody {
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
}

#dialogbox>div>dilogboxfoot {
  background: #666;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="dilogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div id="dilogboxhead" style="text-align: left;"></div>
  <div id="dilogboxbody" style="text-align: center;"></div>
  <div id="dilogboxfoot" style="text-align: right;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Rory But i want to keep `Outer Border` for that can you please suggest me what i need to change

Comment: To do that remove the `style` attribute from `#dialogbox` in the HTML and set `border` in the CSS on that element. I've updated the example to show you how